# Expected an identifier and instead saw 'else'. Missing semicolon in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is the code i have atm. It Say "Expected an identifier and instead saw 'else'. Missing semicolon." for the "else" in -

```
if(fight === "Fight");
{
    alert("You Fought The Pikachu And Won!");
}
else
{
    alert("You Ran From The Pikachu And Got Away To Saftey");
}
```

Comment: You're showing us two problems. 1) YOu have a semicolon after the "if" statement -- that's illegal. It should be `if (fight === "Fight") { } else { } (no semicolon in the if block). 2) You're asking us to refactor your code. Which question do you have?

Comment: Once you get the syntax errors worked out, I recommend you look at codereview.stackexchange.com for help in refactoring code.

Comment: This is the second time in 16hrs I've seen this come up.

Answer (score 3):

Should be obvious from the error message, but an if statement does not end with a semicolon.

replace

```
if(fight === "Fight"); // <- SYNTAX ERROR
{
    alert("You Fought The Pikachu And Won!");
}
else
```

with

```
if(fight === "Fight")
{
    alert("You Fought The Pikachu And Won!");
}
else
```

As for shortening, you could start be removing the uneccessary switch / case -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/naNk9/